# Python Attribute error in web scraping for a popup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to web scrape https://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/AWP%20%7C%20Atheris%20%28Field-Tested%29 and extract the data regarding the ***price of items*** sorted with there ***Inspect in Game*** link.

You can find the ***Inspect in Game*** button by clicking on the arrow popup which appears when you move the cursor on the image of any listed item below.
I managed to scrape the data of prices but, from the same method the Inspect in Game link isn't scraping.

Here's my code

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re

print("Fetching Data")
url = 'https://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/AWP%20%7C%20Atheris%20%28Field-Tested%29'
response = requests.get(url)
# getting the source code of page response.text
data = response.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data,'html.parser')

jobs = soup.find_all('div',{'class':re.compile('market_listing_row market_recent_listing_row listing_''\d')})


for job in jobs:
    price_tag = job.find('span',{'class':'market_listing_price market_listing_price_with_fee'})
    price = price_tag.text[8:] if price_tag else "Sold!"
    link = job.find('a',{'class':'popup_menu_item'}).get('href')
    print('PRICE : ',price,link)
```

I got error `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'` which is probably because this class appears in html code when someone click on the arrow button on the picture, and in the code i am unable to do so. Can anyone suggest me a way, so that i can get the link of Inspect in Game button

Comment: If what you're looking for isn't in the static HTML source for the page, then you may want to look at using Selenium for this.

Comment: No, i dont want to use selenium for this because that opens browser, I am looking for a way like XPATH or javascript whichever can work. Sorry if my concepts are wrong, i am new to python

Comment: @MarqDan you can use `selenium` with `headless` option as well. but if you want to use `requests` only, are you aware that `steamcommunity` is protected with `CAPTCHA`? also please include an sample of desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go through the API. I believe it already doesn't include sold items:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re
import math
import time

print("Fetching Data")

with requests.Session() as s:
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.149 Safari/537.36'}

    s.get('https://steamcommunity.com/')
    cookiesDict = s.cookies.get_dict()

    headers.update({'Cookie':'sessionid=' + cookiesDict['sessionid']})

    url = 'https://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/AWP%20%7C%20Atheris%20%28Field-Tested%29/render/'
    payload = {
    'query':'', 
    'start': '0',
    'count': '100',
    'country': 'US',
    'language': 'english',
    'currency': '1'}


    results = {}
    jsonData = s.get(url, params=payload, headers=headers).json()
    total_count = jsonData['total_count']
    total_pages = math.ceil(total_count/100)
    for page in range(0,total_pages):
        #page=1
        time.sleep(5)    
        payload = {
            'query':'', 
            'start': '%s' %(page*100),
            'count': '100',
            'country': 'US',
            'language': 'english',
            'currency': '1'}

        jsonData = s.get(url, params=payload, headers=headers).json()
        results.update(jsonData['listinginfo'])
        print ('Aquired page %s of %s...' %(page, total_pages))


for k, v in results.items():
    price = (v['converted_price'] + v['converted_fee']) / 100
    link = v['asset']['market_actions'][0]['link']
    print('PRICE : $%.02f %s' %(price, link))
```

**Output:**

```
....
PRICE : $4.64 steam://rungame/730/76561202255233023/+csgo_econ_action_preview%20M%listingid%A%assetid%D2353320232219212327
PRICE : $4.64 steam://rungame/730/76561202255233023/+csgo_econ_action_preview%20M%listingid%A%assetid%D5237312699887394313
PRICE : $4.64 steam://rungame/730/76561202255233023/+csgo_econ_action_preview%20M%listingid%A%assetid%D17060803922484197923
PRICE : $4.64 steam://rungame/730/76561202255233023/+csgo_econ_action_preview%20M%listingid%A%assetid%D3054184006200365805
PRICE : $4.64 steam://rungame/730/76561202255233023/+csgo_econ_action_preview%20M%listingid%A%assetid%D5237312699887394313
....
```

Comment: And There’s tons of other data included in that json response. Just have to look through and make sense of what is what.

Comment: i went from a similar but small approach, my code is here https://pastebin.com/TGSxNS7T but the problem in it that it replaces the value for same keys, resulting in total but less number of item, any solution for this then please tell, it would help me

Comment: I’ll take a look tomorrow.

Comment: looks like your code only returns max of 40 items. You need to include headers with cookies in there I believe.

Comment: if we replace the url by https://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/Special%20Agent%20Ava%20%7C%20FBI/render/ , i am getting an error near the step "aquired page 24", error type :`TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable` can you guess why this is happening. Due to this error i am able to print around 2200 items with their link but there are total 6000 items